# Nested Dictionary Navigation and Copying

Tags: python

I've been working on a script to create a list of orders that contain specific products from a BigCommerce XML order export. I had what I thought was a finished script and realized that I didn't account for removing irrelevant products from nested product dictionaries. To filter the unnecessary products out, I created a dictionary to hold the keys to remove from the `productdict` but it's not as straight forward as the final for loop in the function to remove entire orders from the dictionaries. The issue is in else statement of

```
if productdict[order][product]['Product_SKU'] == recall_product
```

Below is a sample of the 2 print statements in the function in sequence for reference (sensitive info removed).

```
order1

{'product1': {'Product_Qty': '1', 'Product_SKU': 'product1sku'}}

order2

{'product1': {'Product_Qty': '1', 'Product_SKU': 'product1sku'}}

order3

{'product1': {'Product_Qty': '1', 'Product_SKU': 'product1sku'}, 'product2': {'Product_Qty': '1', 'Product_SKU': 'product2sku'}}
```

The function is below. The else statement needs to identify the irrelevant products and copy them to delproduct dictionary. Key/Value pairs with nested dictionaries or simply the order number and product number.

```
def remove_unneeded_orders():
    deldict = {}
    delproduct = {}
    count = 1
    for order in productdict:
        print(order) #order numbers
        cnt = 1
        print(productdict[order]) #products
        for product in productdict[order]:
            if len(productdict[order].keys()) > 1: #fixing issue with handling multiple products
                if productdict[order][product]['Product_SKU'] == recall_product:
                    continue
                else:
                    pass # Problem is here!
            else:
                if productdict[order][product]['Product_SKU'] == recall_product:
                    continue
                else:
                    deldict[order] = i
            cnt += 1
        count += 1

    # Remove products from both dictionaries
    for order in deldict:
        del productdict[order]
        del orderdict[order]
```

Some things I've tried...

```
delproduct = productdict[order][product]
```

delproduct contains `{'Product_Qty': '1', 'Product_SKU': 'GUM-RGW-030-1500D8-HH'}` I wanted this to be nested inside a dictionary with the product number.

```
delproduct[order][product] = productdict[order][product]
```

Receive error `delproduct[order][product] = productdict[order][product] KeyError: 'order3'` The error is in `delproduct[order][product]`.

```
print(productdict[order].keys())
```

Result:

```
dict_keys(['product1', 'product2'])
dict_keys(['product1', 'product2'])
dict_keys(['product1', 'product2'])
dict_keys(['product1', 'product2'])
dict_keys(['product1', 'product2'])
dict_keys(['product1', 'product2'])
dict_keys(['product1', 'product2'])`
```

Inside the product for loop
print(productdict[order][product])

```
{'Product_Qty': '1', 'Product_SKU': 'SKU1'}

{'Product_Qty': '1', 'Product_SKU': 'SKU2'}

{'Product_Qty': '1', 'Product_SKU': 'SKU3'}

{'Product_Qty': '1', 'Product_SKU': 'SKU4'}

{'Product_Qty': '1', 'Product_SKU': 'SKU5'}

{'Product_Qty': '1', 'Product_SKU': 'SKU6'}

{'Product_Qty': '1', 'Product_SKU': 'SKU7'}
```

Ideal output would be something like:

```
delproduct =  {order1: {product1: {'Product_Qty': '1', 'Product_SKU':  'SKU6'}}, 
            order2: {product1: {'Product_Qty': '1', 'Product_SKU':  'SKU7'}}}
```

It could also be something like below but the script is focused on dictionaries, I've tried to avoid mixed data types as much as possible because I'm no master and not trying to complicate it. (although maybe that's complicating it)

```
delproduct = {order1: [product1, product2],
             order2: [product1]}
```

**Edit1**
The order numbers and product numbers should match the source dictionaries.

**Edit2**
Variables have been renamed to be more understandable. Hopefully I got them all.

Comment: What do you WANT?  I don't think you ever showed us what your ideal output would be.

Comment: I haven't waded through the somewhat complicated code to figure out the core issue, but one thing to import that I can see immediately is using better variable names. If you changed `i` and `j` to whatever meaningful value you were using as the keys into the various dictionaries, it would be a whole lot easier to reason about the code. Similarly, it might make sense to name the variables used for the dictionaries better, with names like `products_in_order` or something. Finally, looping over the `items()` of a dictionary is often very convenient, because you can name both the key and the value

Comment: @Blckknght Renaming the variables was the next step after having a work script but I guess I'll expedite that. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: Good variable names can really help debugging, as you can notice that you're trying to index a dictionary that maps from order IDs to something but your key is a product ID. I don't know if that's what's happening here, but I'd guess its something like that.

Comment: I'm definitely still a noob at coding. I've taken care of the variable renaming. Hopefully that will help some poor soul help me. Your suggestion of the key being a product ID may be the issue but it's been a struggle getting this far. I'll re-read the code to see if I can figure it out with the new names.I'll try adding some additional comments to the code to explain it more soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want to remove nested dictionaries according to their "Product_SKU" key?

If so, do as follows:

```py
orders = {
    "order1": {"product1": {"Product_Qty": "1", "Product_SKU": "SKU1"}},
    "order2": {"product1": {"Product_Qty": "1", "Product_SKU": "SKU2"}},
    "order3": {
        "product1": {"Product_Qty": "1", "Product_SKU": "SKU2"},
        "product2": {"Product_Qty": "1", "Product_SKU": "SKU3"},
    },
}

sku_to_remove = "SKU2"

result = {}
for order, products in orders.items():
    for product, product_infos in products.items():
        sku = product_infos["Product_SKU"]
        if sku == sku_to_remove:
            continue
        # here setdefault adds an empty dict for the order if not already there
        result.setdefault(order, {})[product] = product_infos.copy()

print(result)
```

which prints:

```py
{
    "order1": {"product1": {"Product_Qty": "1", "Product_SKU": "SKU1"}},
    "order3": {"product2": {"Product_Qty": "1", "Product_SKU": "SKU3"}},
}
```

---

Beginner friendly alternative without usage of `setdefault` or comprehension:

```py
res = {}
for order, products in orders.items():
    prods = {}
    for prod, infos in products.items():
        if infos["Product_SKU"] != "SKU2":
            prods[prod] = infos
    if prods:  # not empty
        res[order] = prods
```

---

Most explicit way, might be the best to construct on (better design):

```py
def filter_products(products: dict, function: callable):
    return {prod: infos for prod, infos in products.items() if function(infos)}

def is_product_ok(product_infos):
    # Can become arbitrarily complex without changing rest of the code
    return product_infos["Product_SKU"] != "SKU2"

res = {}
for order, products in orders.items():
    prods = filter_products(products, is_product_ok)
    if prods:
        res[order] = prods
```

---

One-liner, for the fun, but not recommended:

```py
res = {
    order: prods
    for order, products in orders.items()
    if (  # check dict not empty
        prods := {  # walrus operator
            prod: infos
            for prod, infos in products.items()
            if infos["Product_SKU"] != sku_to_remove
        }
    )
}
```

Comment: This solution worked great! I tweaked it a little to fit the rest of the script. All-in-all, this trimmed down the script by 10+ lines so huge thanks! This approach will also help me make the rest of the script more efficient. Again... Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome! Actually you can even do it in a single line (using dict comprehension and walrus operator), see bottom of my edit. I also added other alternatives, one that is beginner-friendly and another to show how you can deconstruct the problem in multiple simple functions.

Comment: Thanks for all the additional feedback @paime! Once I have some free time, I'm planning to rewrite a lot of the script so this is perfect for me to consider when doing so.